# Check if condition from json

Tags: android, json, string, if-statement

I have an int value lets say 10, now i want to check whether 10 is less than 50 or not so i will write if condition as :
if(10<50){
}
But the problem here is that "<50" is coming from json in string format. So how to evaluate this condition?

Comment: Try, int number = jsonObject.getInt("number");

if(10 < number){
//code
}

Not sure if your looking for this?

Comment: Or maybe your looking for this? 
int something = Integer.parseInt(number); and then use something in the if statement

Comment: check if String.charAt(position) can help ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that JSON response will be in following format -

```
*characterNUMBER*
```

then you can get `int` value as follows -

```
    String test = "<50";
    int value1 = Integer.parseInt(test.replace("<", ""));

    /*
    * Using substring method
    * String.subString(beginIndex, endIndex);
    * Note: beginIndex is inclusive but endIndex is the exclusive
    * */
    int value2 = Integer.parseInt(test.substring(1,test.length()));
```

`value1` and `value2` both will extract int from that String.

For ease of use do create a method inside your Json POJO to return integer values-

```
public class JSONResponce{
    
    .....

    @SerializedName("some_string_value")
    private String stringValue;

    public int getIntValue(){
        //do conversion of String to actual int here
        return Integer.parseInt(stringValue.substring(1,stringValue.length()));
    }
    ....
}
```

Happy coding !